# MS-Access Check box IF statements

Tags: ms-access, checkbox

How would i add a check("chk3") that will be ticked when ("Customer order Number") field has been inputted. when an order number is entered, then the check box will tick..

i also would like to know if it is possible that When the value field ("Value") is under £10,000 then the check box ("chk2") will tick. if it is over £10,000 then it will not tick

[image]

Comment: If the purpose of the check box is simply to identify that you have an order number, it seems a bit redundant, simply check if there is an order number or not? Similarly with the value, you can always query the value to produce a result list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `AfterUpdate` events for such validations.

`Nz` function checks for null value and converts them to empty string & 0 respectively

**For Customer Order Number:**

```
Private Sub txtCustomerOrderNo_AfterUpdate()
    If Nz(Me.txtCustomerOrderNo, "") <> "" Then
        Me.chk3 = True
    Else
        Me.chk3 = False
    End If
End Sub
```

**For Project value is less than 10K:**

```
Private Sub txtProjEstimate_AfterUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    If Nz(Me.txtProjEstimate, 0) < 10000 Then
        Me.chk2 = True
    Else
        Me.chk2 = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @MattH Welcome :-)

Comment: Would it be possible to check to box for the check box to tick? e.g. If Nz(Me.Combo604 And Combo581, "") <> "" Then
        Me.Check628 = True
    Else
        Me.Check628 = False
    End If
End Sub

Comment: @MattH Should be like this `If Nz(Me.Combo604, False) And Nz(Combo581, False) Then`

Answer (score 2):

Depends on your version of Access.  In older versions, it was the AfterUpdate event.  In newer ones, I think it's OnExit.

In whichever event of Customer Order Number, just set its value to True.

```
Private Sub CustomerOrderNumber_Exit(Cancel As Integer)
  Me.chk3 = true
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

It sort of depends what you're trying to do with the `chk3` validation. If you're looking for a specific structure. For instance, a 10 digit number, then you would want a validation along those lines within the `IF Statement`. Something like:

(Using `AfterUpdate`)

```
If Me.[Customer order Number] LIKE "##########" Then
    Me.chk3 = True
End If
```

Similiarly with the validation on the `ck2` > £10,000 (assuming this is an appropriately designated currency field):

```
If Me.[Value] <= 10000 Then
    Me.chk2 = True
End If
```